# Two issues with the uplodify

Tags: php, jquery

I have implemented [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for my website. I am successfully able to upload the file and thumbnails to the server. Could anyone please tell me how can I display those thumbnails on the website.

Uploadify implementation

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'removeCompleted' : false,
    'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
    'buttonText' : 'Add/Edit Images',
'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
     'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
    alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
},
onComplete : function(event,queueID,fileObj,response,data) {


 $('#thumbnails).append(<img src=\"' + response + '\" />');
}
        // Put your options here - ashish tyagi
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<tr><input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" /></tr>
<tr><div id=\"thumbnail"\></div></tr>
```

I am also not able to see the cancel button and I need to display the thumbnail instead of name of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the file name in the onUploadSuccess event, and you should know the directory the files have got uploaded to. Whenever you know these two parts of the URL, you are able to build the URL to the image you want to include on the page.

```
$(function () {
    var base_url = "http://example.com/";

    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'removeCompleted': false,
         'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
         'uploader': 'uploadify.php',
         'buttonText': 'Add/Edit Images',
         'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
         'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
            $('#thumbnails').append('<img src=\"' + base_url + file.name + '\" />');
         }
    });
});
```

And I do not know what is wrong with the cancel image, but my guess is that the browser is trying to get it from wrong URL. Try to use the whole path to the image file.

Comment: I have tried the absolute path for the image and it is not working

Comment: Is the upload successful at all then? Can you see the file you uploaded on the server?

Comment: Yes, I can see the file at my server, it is even creating the thumbnail properly